# Rails view helper display badge and text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I have an app I'm working on with Rails 3.2.x and Bootstrap 2.  I have a view helper which returns different text based on a call's status and attributes.

```
def status(call)
   if call.call_status == "open" && call.transfer_date > Time.zone.now + 15.minutes
     "Scheduled"
   elsif call.wait_return == "yes" && call.call_status == "open"
     "Active/Wait and Return"
   elsif call.call_status == "close"
     "Closed Call"
   elsif call.call_status == "cancel"
     "Cancelled Call"
   else
     "Active"
   end
 end
```

I'd like to refactor this to where each condition's text returns a bootstrap badge with the text inside of it.  I looked at the API docs for `content_tag` and I think this is what I need but I'm not 100% sure on how to make this work.

Any help or refactoring advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by splitting that large method into small ones, something like this:

```
class Call
  def scheduled?
    call_status == "open" && call.transfer_date > Time.zone.now + 15.minutes
  end

  def closed?
    call_status == "close"
  end

  ...
end
```

Then your `status` method will look like this:

```
def status(call)
  text = case
    when call.scheduled?
      "Scheduled"
    when call.cancelled?
      "Active/Wait and Return"
    when call.closed?
      "Closed Call"
  end
  content_tag(:span, text, class: "badge")
end
```

Hope it helps you to refactor your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I knew I was overlooking something.  This is a great start. :)